# WSDL imported with C++ Builder Wizard (C++ Builder Xe6 Pro)

Tags: c++, web-services, wsdl, c++builder, ebay-api

i am pretty lame with using wsdl importer wizard with c++ Builder (XE6 Pro)
 but finnally managed to properly import EBAY WSDL:

http://developer.ebay.com/webservices/latest/ebaySvc.wsdl

I can successfully run simple calls, but problem arises , when trying to set (or get )
Enum values.
At this point i am getting beautifull access violation after compilation. 
Relevant piece of code:

```
void __fastcall TEbay::IndexBClick(TObject *Sender)
{

CallName="GetMyeBaySelling";
UnicodeString PUrl =  MakeLink();
_di_eBayAPIInterface EbayCall = GeteBayAPIInterface(false,PUrl,HTP1);

CustomSecurityHeaderType *HDR = new RequesterCredentials;

HDR->eBayAuthToken=AuthToken;
HDR->Credentials = new UserIdPasswordType();
HDR->Credentials->AppId=AppId;
HDR->Credentials->DevId=DevId;
HDR->Credentials->AuthCert=CertId;
_di_ISOAPHeaders headers = EbayCall;
HTP1->SOAPHeaders->Send(HDR);
HTP1->SOAPHeaders->SetOwnsSentHeaders(True);

//GeteBayOfficialTimeRequest TR =  new GeteBayOfficialTimeRequestType();
GetMyeBaySellingRequest *TR = new GetMyeBaySellingRequest();
GetMyeBaySellingResponse *ER =new GetMyeBaySellingResponse();
//ShowMessage(PUrl);
TR->Version=Version;
 TR->ErrorLanguage="en_GB";
   // This one raises error
 TR->SoldList->OrderStatusFilter=OrderStatusFilterCodeType::All;
 ShowMessage("2");

ER = EbayCall->GetMyeBaySelling(TR);
TDateTime ACK = ER->Timestamp->AsDateTime;
 ShowMessage(UnicodeString("ODP:")+ACK);
// EbayCall->GeteBayOfficialTime(ER);

delete TR;
delete ER;
delete HDR;
}
```

Violation comes when i try to set up OrderStatusFilter or any enum values.

Declaration: (ebasvc.h) :

```
enum class OrderStatusFilterCodeType   /* "urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents"[GblSmpl] */
{
 All,
 AwaitingPayment,
 AwaitingShipment,
 PaidAndShipped,
 CustomCode
};

class OrderStatusFilterCodeType_TypeInfoHolder : public TObject {
  OrderStatusFilterCodeType __instanceType;
public:
__published:
  __property OrderStatusFilterCodeType __propType = { read=__instanceType };
};
```

I am getting mad allready with this, could anybody help me run this $#&^#$&^ ??

Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
TR->SoldList->OrderStatusFilter=OrderStatusFilterCodeType::All;
```

Looks like you are trying to assign a value to a property on the *SoldList* object, yet I can't see where you have created that object. Try the following.

```
TR->SoldList = new ItemListCustomizationType();
TR->SoldList->OrderStatusFilter=OrderStatusFilterCodeType::All;
```

Comment: YESSS ! You're great :) i missed that SoldList is ItemListCustomizationType Object. I tried to initialize ItemListCustomizationType "standalone", but it din't do the job. Now it works like a harm. Thank You!